# assetic:watch produces empty css files

Tags: css, sass, symfony, assetic

I am using symfony3 as a newbie. I have installed sass on my fedora system and I try to use the sass filter to convert my scss files into css. I use the assetic bundle.
I have created an assets dir in web which contains a scss and a css dir.
My config.yml contains the following:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        jsqueeze: ~
        sass: ~
        compass: ~
```

My twig template include the following:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter="sass" output="assets/css/app.css"        
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets/scss/main.scss"
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}  
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/app.css') }}"> 
{% endblock %}
```

After having launched

```
php bin/console assetic:watch
```

each time I bring a change in main.scss, .css files are generated in web/assets/css (app.css, app_main_1.css) but they are absolutely empty.

If I run

```
sass web/assets/scss/main.scss web/assets/css/app.css
```

a valid css file is generated.

Could somebody help me understanding what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Giving the full path to sass and compass in the configuration file solves the problem.